# What is this parentheses notation? $\binom{n}{i}$

Tags: notation

I have an equation:

$$2^k\;\sum_{i=0}^t\binom{n}{i}=2^n$$

The context is perfect error correcting codes. My question is, what do the parentheses represent?

Comment: I am not familiar with “perfect error correcting codes” but it could be the binomial expansion.

Comment: binomial coefficients

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: It could be binomial coefficients. However the equation does not make much sense. What are unknown variables in the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the so-called binomial coefficients. Computing them is easy:

$$ \binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$

This counts the number of ways to select $k$ objects from $n$ in which order doesn't matter, i.e., the number of combinations.